# Redirect simple url to https in php codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, https

I have one website its url is currently thereviewplace.com. i have ssl certificate so i want to redirect this url to https://thereviewplace.com i have serch over net and i have tried many htaccess code like

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://thereviewplace.com/$1 [R,L]
```

But it gives error like 
"The page isn't redirecting properly"

Please provide solution.

Answer (score 2):

first of all set

```
$config['base_url'] = "";
```

Codeigniter will automatically get it.

Second, use this rule in `.htaccess` file :

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thereviewplace\.com$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^ https://thereviewplace.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Answer (score 1):

> > **In `config/base_url()` set like this `https://www.thereviewplace.com`**

Because in your page source

[image: 01]

If i access page like `http://www.thereviewplace.com` works fine

Comment: i have also tried this by changing my base url http://thereviewplace.com to https://thereviewplace.com but its not working.

Answer (score 1):

In your CodeIgniter settings do this:

```
$config['base_url'] = "";
```

You need to check the `%{HTTPS}` variable:

```
RewriteEngine On
# This will enable the Rewrite capabilities

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS

RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
# This rule will redirect users from their original location, to the same location but using HTTPS.
# i.e.  http://www.example.com/foo/ to https://www.example.com/foo/
# The leading slash is made optional so that this will work either in httpd.conf
# or .htaccess context
```

> **Source**
>
> https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS

Although the recommended way is to put this in your httpd.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName mysite.example.com
   DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
   Redirect permanent /secure https://mysite.example.com/secure
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
   ServerName mysite.example.com
   DocumentRoot /usr/local/apache2/htdocs
   SSLEngine On
# etc...
</VirtualHost>
```

> **Source**
>
> https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RedirectSSL

Comment: Where is the httpd.conf located on your server?  in Linux it is usually located at /etc/apache2/conf/httpd.conf ... on Windows it will be in the location of where ever Apache is installed

Comment: actually i have no rights to update this. so can i update from my root folder??

Comment: If you cannot update your httpd.conf, update your `.htaccess` file using the first example in the answer.  If you had access to your httpd.conf you could update that file using the second example/

Comment: thanks i have added below code in httacess file 

RewriteEngine On
# This will enable the Rewrite capabilities

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS

RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
# This rule will redirect users from their original location, to the same location but using HTTPS.
# i.e.  http://www.example.com/foo/ to https://www.example.com/foo/
# The leading slash is made optional so that this will work either in httpd.conf
# or .htaccess context

Comment: :( but still there is This web page has a redirect loop

ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: i have found another way.
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thereviewplace.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.thereviewplace.com/$1 [R=301,L]

its working see my website

Comment: Is there anywhere in your code that you are redirecting? Maybe CodeIgniter is trying to redirect to port 80 so then it loops

Comment: Did you update the config setting to this `$config['base_url'] = "";` ?

Answer (score 0):

put this in your htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

and in you application/config/config.php edit the follwoing

```
$config['base_url'] = 'https://thereviewplace.com/';
```

Answer (score 0):

Set base_url in config file with http and try this .htaccess file

RewriteEngine On

```
# Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your best answers.

I got my questions solution. And below is the code which i have used in my website.

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^thereviewplace.com [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.thereviewplace.com/$1 [R=301,L]

Now there is no any error is coming and working properly.